# What problems maybe happen if I remove “wp-” prefix from wordpress folders and files?

Tags: php, wordpress, prefix

I want to hide wordpress signs from my site. So I don't want other people know that I built the website via WordPress. So I decided to remove `wp-` prefixes from all wordpress folders and files. And I also removed `wp-` prefixes from file contents with Notepad++. So my question is what problems maybe happen if I removed `wp-` prefixes ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The world could end. Just saying.

Comment: You'll end up with a pretty big change you're missing just 1 prefix; that might break it down completely. It can be done in theory I guess, but only when being very precise. Just to make a small statement; Wordpress is created by the community. Why shouldn't you give them the credits? The only reason why WP is great as it is, is because it's name is wide-spread. Why don't contribute to that?

Comment: I found solution http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1507/steps-to-take-to-hide-the-fact-a-site-is-using-wordpress

Answer (score 1):

All relative/absolute links will be obsolete. You'll have to edit the complete set of files and remove all its appearances, and even then, it might not work. I have never worked around much with wordpress though!

Answer (score 1):

if you could remove all traces from all files in the installation, that would be one thing, but you might miss something and then it would be broken. but on the other hand, removing all traces of wordpress might actually violate the license agreement for the wordpress software. you might want to check on that before you actually do it.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to change every occurrence of the prefix for it to work. Which means going through thousands lines of codes, and is not practical really. And you would need to do that on every Wordpress update.

And even if it works after that, it won't be too hard to learn if the website uses Wordpress, as it will generate the same code.

Answer (score 1):

I can tell you three things.

First, yes. It can be done. Te New York Times has done it.

Second, just changing the directory name is not the solution. Those directories are referred somewhere, isn't it? What happens to those?

Thirdly, if you want to use WordPress, be proud that you are using the most actively developed Open Source blog CMS, and show it off.

If someone is out to find if you are really using WordPress, he/she will find it out eventually. There are a million ways to tell that you are using WordPress, and it rarely involves going through your content directory names.

Answer (score 0):

You can use some plugins such as "hide_my_wp" or etc. I didn't use them in person but think they have been created to do what you are looking for. Just google them and you will find some out.

Answer (score 0):

I'm developing a [wordpress](https://github.com/ziobru/no_prefix_WordPress_setup) version who will not use the `wp-` prefix for files and folder.

During the debug I can tell you that it's an adventure to fix all the issues related to files renaming, but if you take care to modify all the core files it will work perfectly. If you only want to hide your login page or admin area, you can google for a plugin, there are a lot of them that are doing this thing.